# Error "illegalArgumentException: no such vertex in graph" but vertexSet() returns the vertex

Tags: java, algorithm, processing, jgrapht, digraphs

I use a Flood Fill Algorithm to look if the 1s and 2s of a matrix are making a loop.

For example:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Will become:

```
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 2 2 3 0 0 
    0 0 0 3 3 3 0 3 0 0 
    0 0 0 3 0 0 3 3 0 0 
    0 0 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I initialize the algorithm at a given point which is (2,7) and the the algorithm turns into 3s every 1 that is linked to the starting point. 
I wanted to also implement a digraph (using jgrapht), each 1 being a vertex, and having one edge being created between two 1s which are next to each other. So each time the algorithm turns a 1 into a 3, it makes both the 3 a vertex and creates an edge with the last spot filled.

Note: I use reactivision, so each marker detected is added to the matrix as a 1. Since I can't test right now with 10 markers, I added a matrix to the program.

Here is the part of my code doing this:
[EDIT]: I pasted my whole code now since I can't find the error

```
  import TUIO.*;
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.jgrapht.alg.*;
import org.jgrapht.demo.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.jgrapht.*;
import org.jgrapht.graph.*;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.alg.*;
TuioProcessing tuioClient;

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Create matrix
static int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];

// Create Grid
int cols = 10, rows = 10;
int rectangleWidth = 100;
int rectangleHeight = 60;

// these are some helper variables which are used
// to create scalable graphical feedback

float cursor_size = 15;
float object_size = 60;
float table_size = 760;
float scale_factor = 1;
boolean verbose = false; // print console debug messages
boolean callback = true; // updates only after callbacks

// Variables to mesure time
long startTime = 0;
long time ;

// Variables to caracterise each ficudial
int x, y, k, l, iD;
String myType;

// Types of components: V: Vertical / H: Horizontal /ER: Elbow Right / EL: Elbow Left / LI: Left Intersection / VI: Vertical Intersection 
// Their position in the list matches their iD
String [] fiducialsList = {
  "R300", "R3OO", "R600", "R600", "V", "V", "H", "ER", "H", "ER", "EL", "EL", "R100", "R100", "R900", "R900", "EL", "V", "V", "ER", "H", "H", "Box", "LI", "VI"
}; 


//Create the directed graph
public static DirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
public static Point firstPoint = new Point(2,7);

// --------------------------------------------------------------
ArrayList<Fiducial> activList = new ArrayList<Fiducial>();
public class Fiducial {

  public float x;
  public float y;
  public int iD;
  public String myType;


  public Fiducial(float x, float y, int iD, String myType) 
  {
    this.myType = myType;
    this.iD = iD;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  @Override
    public String toString() {
    return ("[iD="+iD+" x="+x+" y="+y +" type="+myType+"]");
  }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------
//Time measurement: every lapse of time spent by the user on a circuit is stored here
ArrayList <Time> timeSpent = new ArrayList <Time> ();
public class Time {

  public long time ;

  public Time (long time)
  { 
    this.time = time;
  }
  @Override 
    public String toString () {
    return ("time spent on this circuit:" + time );
  }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------
void setup() {


  size(1000, 600);
  noCursor();
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (2,7));
  // periodic updates
  if (!callback) {
    frameRate(60); //<>//
    loop();
  } else noLoop(); // or callback updates 
  //int[][] array = new int[10][10];
  //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
  tuioClient  = new TuioProcessing(this);
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));

  startTime = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("#vertex: "+ directedGraph.vertexSet());
}


// --------------------------------------------------------------
void draw() {

  // Begin loop for columns
  for ( k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for ( l = 0; l < rows; l++) {
      fill(255);
      stroke(0);
      rect(k*rectangleWidth, l*rectangleHeight, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight);
    }
  }

  matrix [1][5]= 2;
  matrix [1][6]= 2;
  matrix [2][5]= 2;
  matrix [2][6]= 2;
  matrix [3][5]=1;
  matrix [2][7]=1;
  matrix [4][6]=1;
  matrix [3][5]=1;
  matrix [4][6]=1;
  matrix [4][7]=0;
  matrix [3][4]=1;
  matrix [3][3]=1;
  matrix [3][7]=1;
  matrix [3][7]=1;
  matrix [3][7]=1;
  matrix [3][7]=1;
  matrix [4][3]=1;
  matrix [5][3]=1;
  matrix [5][4]=1;
  matrix [5][5]=1;
  matrix [5][6]=1;
  matrix [6][6]=1;
  matrix [7][6]=1;
  matrix [3][2]=1;
  matrix [3][1]=1;
  matrix [3][0]=1;

  // Print Matrix
  for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
      System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
  System.out.print("\n");

  // This part detects the fiducial markers 
  float obj_size = object_size*scale_factor; 
  float cur_size = cursor_size*scale_factor; 
  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjectList = tuioClient.getTuioObjectList();
  for (int i=0; i<tuioObjectList.size (); i++) {

     //System.out.println("#vertex: "+ directedGraph.vertexSet());

    TuioObject tobj= tuioObjectList.get(i);
    stroke(0);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));
    rotate(tobj.getAngle());
    rect(-80, -40, 80, 40);
    popMatrix();
    fill(255);
    x = round(10*tobj.getX ());
    y = round(10*tobj.getY ());
    iD = tobj.getSymbolID();
    // directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(x,y));
    int taille = fiducialsList.length;
    for (int o = 0; o<taille; o++) {
      if (iD == o) { 
        myType = fiducialsList [o];

      }
    } 

    activList.add(new Fiducial (x, y, iD, myType));
    matrix [x][y] = 1 ;
    circuitState ();
    for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
      for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[p][r] + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
  System.out.println("#vertex: "+ directedGraph.vertexSet());
  //Re-initialize matrix
  for (int[] row : matrix)
    Arrays.fill(row, 0);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
void circuitState () {
  if ( matrix [2][7]==1 ) {
    FloodFill.resolution(args);
    if (matrix [3][5]== 3) {
      System.out.println("Fermé");
    } else {
      long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
      timeSpent.add(new Time (time));
      System.out.println(" Ouvert " + "took" + estimatedTime);
    }
  }
}


// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Implementation of the Flood Fill Algorithm to detect if circuit is closed or not
public static class FloodFill {


  public static void resolution(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Found loop: "+checkIfPositionIsInLoop(matrix, 2, 7, 3));


    //result
    System.out.println("-------------------"); 

    for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
  }

  private static Direction direction;

  public static boolean checkIfPositionIsInLoop(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int fillValue) {
    int targetX = x;
    int targetY = y;

    return fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, x, y, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.LEFT );
  }

  private static boolean fillReachesTargetPosition(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int targetX, int targetY, int fillValue, Direction forbiddenDirection) {

    if (x>=matrix.length)
      return false;
    if (y>=matrix[x].length)
      return false;

    int originValue=matrix[x][y];
    matrix[x][y]=fillValue;

    int xToFillNext;
    int yToFillNext;

    boolean fillingReachedTargetPosition = false;

    // Up
    xToFillNext = x-1;
    yToFillNext = y;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.UP)) {
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (x,y));
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      directedGraph.addEdge(new Point (x,y),new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      return true;

    } else if (xToFillNext>=0 && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.UP)) {  
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (x,y));
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      directedGraph.addEdge(new Point (x,y),new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));      
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.DOWN );


      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Right
    xToFillNext = x;
    yToFillNext = y+1;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX  && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (x,y));
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      directedGraph.addEdge(new Point (x,y),new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      return true;
    } else if (yToFillNext<matrix[xToFillNext].length && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (x,y));
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      directedGraph.addEdge(new Point (x,y),new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.LEFT );
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Down
    xToFillNext = x+1;
    yToFillNext = y;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (x,y));
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      directedGraph.addEdge(new Point (x,y),new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      return true;
    } else if (xToFillNext<matrix.length  && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.DOWN)) {
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (x,y));
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      directedGraph.addEdge(new Point (x,y),new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.UP );  
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Left
    xToFillNext = x;
    yToFillNext = y-1;
    if (xToFillNext==targetX && yToFillNext==targetY && forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.RIGHT)) {
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (x,y));
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      directedGraph.addEdge(new Point (x,y),new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      return true;
    } else if (yToFillNext>=0 && originValue==matrix[xToFillNext][yToFillNext] && !forbiddenDirection.equals(Direction.LEFT)) {

      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (x,y));
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      directedGraph.addEdge(new Point (x,y),new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      fillingReachedTargetPosition = 
        fillReachesTargetPosition(matrix, xToFillNext, yToFillNext, targetX, targetY, fillValue, Direction.RIGHT );
      if (fillingReachedTargetPosition) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
public static class DirectedGraphDemo {
    public  static void graph(String args[]) {
        // constructs a directed graph with the specified vertices and edges

  directedGraph.addVertex(firstPoint);


        // prints the strongly connected components
        System.out.println("Strongly connected components:");
        for (int i = 0; i < stronglyConnectedSubgraphs.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(stronglyConnectedSubgraphs.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println();


    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
ArrayList<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();
public static class Point {

  public int x;
  public int y;

  public  Point(int x, int y) 
  {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  @Override
    public String toString() {
    return ("[x="+x+" y="+y+"]");
  }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// called at the end of each TUIO frame
void refresh(TuioTime frameTime) {
  if (verbose) println("frame #"+frameTime.getFrameID()+" ("+frameTime.getTotalMilliseconds()+")");
  if (callback) redraw();
}
```

However, when I run it, I get an error "illegalArgumentException: no such vertex in graph [x=2 y=7]" which is the starting point. So I tried to define this point as vertex by doing:

```
public static Point firstPoint = new Point(2,7);
```

and then:

```
directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (2,7));
```

but it still won't work I get the same error, always at this line:
      `directedGraph.addEdge(new Point (x,y),new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));` but at different places in the Flood Fill algorithm depending on where Reactivision detects the marker (so it is either in the UP, DOWN, LEFT, or RIGHT section of the algorithm).

I'm completely stuck. I added a print statement so each time the draw method is executed, it returns the vertices of the graph and [2,7] is there ... I can't figure it out, could someone help me ?

Comment: Please post the code that generates the "'unepexted token" error.

Comment: What do you mean by 'at the beginning of the program'? Did you put that line in the right spot?

Comment: it's right under the creation of the digraph, 3rd line here. I tried many spots (that might seem weird but I tried to find the right place to put it)

Comment: @Nibor I edited my question and code. I created a new point and then added it to the graph (in Setup). I still have the error, so to make sure it was added, every time the draw method is executed it returns the list of vertices, and the [2,7] point is there ... I'm stuck, can't figure it out, why is is printing that the vertex is there and then telling me it's not ... I didn't implement any function to clear the vertex set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my error: I had to add:

```
      Point myPoint = new Point(x, y);
      Point myNextPoint = new Point(xToFillNext, yToFillNext);

      directedGraph.addVertex(myPoint);
      directedGraph.addVertex(myNextPoint);
      directedGraph.addEdge(myPoint, myNextPoint);
```

In every section of my Flood Fill algorithm instead of :

```
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (x,y));
      directedGraph.addVertex(new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
      directedGraph.addEdge(new Point (x,y),new Point(xToFillNext,yToFillNext));
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can have outside of functions are **declarations**.

These are declarations:

```
int x, y, k, l, iD;
```

So is this:

```
public static DirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<Point, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
```

But this is not:

```
directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (2,7));
```

You're getting the "unexpected token" compilation error because you can't have statements like this outside of a function.

Move this statement into your `setup()` function instead.

You could also use an **[initializer block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)** to automatically move that piece of code into the class constructor. Just wrap it in curly brackets:

```
{
   directedGraph.addVertex(new Point (2,7)); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I edited my question, added some code and explanations. I first created a new point object named firstPoint, and then I added it to the vertices with the line above. When I ask for the Vertices set to be printed (the statement is in the draw method so It returns it every time it is executed), it does print this point. But I still get the error. I'm completely stuck.